# Scrapy https tutorial

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

everyone!

I'm new to Scrapy framework. And I need to parse wisemapping.com. 
At first, I read official Scrapy tutorial and tried to get access to one of "wisemap" 's, but got an errors:

```
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://app.wisemapping.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)

[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying
<GET https://app.wisemapping.com/c/maps/576786/public> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error

[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <GET https://app.wisemapping.com/c/maps/576786/public> (referer: None)

[scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <500 https://app.wisemapping.com/c/maps/576786/public>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Please, give me an advice to solve problems with following code:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://app.wisemapping.com/c/maps/576786/public',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'wisemape.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigating to https://app.wisemapping.com/c/maps/576786/public gives the error 
"Outch!!. This map is not available anymore.
You do not have enough right access to see this map. This map has been changed to private or deleted."

Does this map exist?  If so, try making it public.

If you know for a fact the map you're trying to access exist, verify the URL you're trying to access is the correct one.